# Chrome & Firefox browser extensions CSS image urls in content scripts

Tags: css, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, css-variables

how can I manage the background image URLs for both Chrome and Firefox browser extension content script in a single CSS file please?

Firefox uses regular relative URL as:

```
background-image: url('/images/my-photo.jpg');
```

Chrome uses messages extension ID URL as:

```
background-image: url('chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/images/my-photo.jpg');
```

This cause development inconvenience as I need to create different CSS files for each browser.

For now I use SASS/SCSS variables as:

```
$imagePath: '/images/';
$imagePath: 'chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/images/';

background-image: url('#{$imagePath}my-photo.jpg');
```

And then I duplicate the file, remove one variable and compile the file.

But it isn't that comfortable to work with different files, is there any idea how to work on a single CSS file and make it works for both browsers please?

I'm not interested in using base64 urls.

I was thinking maybe using CSS native variables together with a media query that will overwrite the variable to a specific browser, but I'm not sure how.

For example something like that:

```
:root {
    --imagePath: '/images/';
}

@media chrome(){
    --imagePath: 'chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/images/';
}

--imageURL: var(--imagePath)+'my-photo.jpg';
background-image: url(var(--imageURL));
```

Comment: Use `@supports (-moz-appearance:none)`, see [Targeting only Firefox with CSS](//stackoverflow.com/a/32455002). You can also use a similar Chrome-only property for chrome sections e.g. [How to apply specific CSS rules to Chrome only?](//stackoverflow.com/q/9328832)

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks using the supports CSS feature query do the work :)

Comment: Can I see your working CSS?